# jQuery Galleriffic issue with jQuery inline

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Seem to be having some issues with executing jQuery code in the "caption" class.

My class ".showmore" lies within the caption section, however when I perform a hover function, it does not seem to execute this jQuery function.

Is there anything within the Galleriffic jQuery that is preventing me from executing this???

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>css/galleriffic-2.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.showmore').hover(function(){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
        });
    </script>

    <div class="caption">    
        <div class="showmore">+</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your `<script>` to the bottom of the page.  Currently `$('.showmore').hover(...)` is executed before the `.showmore` div is written to the page.

Alternatively you can try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.showmore').hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
});
```

This ensures that you're code is executed after the DOM is finished loading.  See [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more information.

Also try passing two functions into the hover event.  It really shouldn't matter (see [source code](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L928)), but typically, [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes in two functions as parameter -- the first is executed when the mouse enters the element and the second is executed when the mouse leaves the element.  Here's an example:

```
$('.showmore').hover(function() { $(this).fadeIn('fast'); },
                     function() { $(this).findOut('fast'); });
```

When only one function is passed in, that function is executed both when the mouse enters and leaves the element.

Also, make sure that you're including jquery to the page.  In the example you posted, it seems you're including the galleriffic and opacityrollover plugins but not jquery core.