# Galleriffic - how to display div on mouseover, hide on mouseout?

Tags: galleriffic

I'm trying to display exif info inside a div when hovering over a div element in the gallery (image or filename). It's easy enough to do outside of the gallery, but when I try to do it with a div element of the gallery, nothing happens because the content is being served up via jquery.galleriffic.js dynamically.

You can see the effect here when you mouseover the image:
http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/post/50833256

I have the exif info to display in a database, so I just need to know how to show/hide the div when hovering over the image. Trial and error would take me a while, so if you're an expert, I'd appreciate some advice on where to place the .bind("mouseover")... statements in jquery.galleriffic.js

This is a similar question, but the problem wasn't resolved:
[jQuery Galleriffic issue with jQuery inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710357/jquery-galleriffic-issue-with-jquery-inline)

Answer (score 0):

Add the exif data to the "caption" area (defined in galleriffic.captionContainerSel), and show/hide with css when you hover the slideshow image.